# Monodroid : Change edittext style(border in red) and after get back to default style

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I put red borders to an editext in certain conditions (using shape) and after I wanted to back to the default android style edittext.

I tried like this :

```
EditText lastName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.lastName);
lastName.SetBackgroundResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.EditBoxBackgroundNormal);
```

It displays long white bar instead of the default style of edittext (black background and gray line).

How I can get this default style of edittext ?

Comment: The link tiny.cc is broken and removed from your post. Please re-update it without using URL shorteners, but the real link.

Answer (score 1):

How do you set that "Error" sign? Instead of removing the background `Drawable` I would just set it with:

```
myEditText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0 , 0, Resource.Drawable.MyErrorIcon, 0);
```

Where `myEditText` is an instance of `EditText` and `Resource.Drawable.MyErrorIcon` is a `Drawable` of your icon you want to display.

You can remove it with:

```
myEditText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0 , 0, 0, 0);
```

By setting the `CompoundDrawables` you will never need to touch the Background Resource of the `EditText`.

Comment: Mhh yes this could be nice. What I wanted to do is to put border of the edittext in red when the value is not good and after get back to default style when edittext value is ok. There is a way to do that ?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that instead of having that in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses attributes to map the correct drawable to the api level, application theme, device configuration, etc. Give the following line of code a try.

```
lastName.SetBackgroundResource(Android.Resource.Attribute.EditTextBackground);
```

Comment: I tried your code but it give this unhandle exception : `Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1010352`

Comment: this isn't possible to save the old background of an edittext with monodroid ? (android-java : `activity.findViewById(id).getBackground();`)